# AppointRequest with SOAP message to MS Dynamics CRM 4.0

Tags: soap, dynamics-crm, webservice-client

I want to execute an AppointmentRequest through a SOAP message to Dynamics CRM 4.0
The following SOAP message I am posting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:m0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/CoreTypes" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <m:CrmAuthenticationToken>
      <m0:AuthenticationType>0</m0:AuthenticationType>
      <m0:OrganizationName>MyOrg</m0:OrganizationName>
      <m0:CallerId>4d6792b2-d96f-de11-bc90-005056a243de</m0:CallerId>
    </m:CrmAuthenticationToken>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <m:Execute>
      <m:request xsi:type="SearchRequest">
        <AppointmentRequest>
          <ServiceId>7b94C2A1D8-C201-DE11-B7B1-0022640DEB74</ServiceId>
        </AppointmentRequest>
      </m:request>
    </m:Execute>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I am receiving back an error from CRM :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode><faultstring>Server was unable to process request.</faultstring><detail><error>
  <code>0x80040203</code>
  <description>request</description>
  <type>Platform</type>
</error></detail></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Anyone with experience on this?
I would be very thankfull if someone can help me or gives me tips

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The error code `0x80040203` means InvalidArgument. See the list of [Error Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb930493.aspx).

Enable the tracing (See [How to enable tracing in Microsoft Dynamics CRM](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907490/en)) which should give you more information about what's going wrong.